# Ubuntu freezes when I print

Tags: xubuntu, printing, 16.04, hp, freeze

I have an HP LASERJET 6P plugged on the parrallel port. (/dev/lp0)
It is turned on. 
I tried many ways to print anything

`echo "test" > /dev/lp0`

`lpr filename`

even pressing the button "print a test page" after driver intallation.

everytime the system seems freezed. the keyboard and the mouse are not responding. I have to power off the computer.
I am on XUbuntu 16.04.
The printer works great with the same computer on Windows XP.

Any help would be appreciated
:D

Comment: Most of Ubuntu 16 problems are bugs and are solved by updates or installation of newer version of kernel. Try this one http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't work.
I followed the instructions but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Install HPLIP Toolbox from Ubuntu Software Center.

Printer>add>Select your printer device>on conections choose HPLIP LINUX Imaging and printing

Answer (score 0):

For Hp Printers

```
hp-doctor - installs dependencies
hp-setup - (plugged in  to usb)
hp-setup - <ip-address-assigned at end of steup>
```

Comment: hp-setup disabled the "parralel port" option
-> [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/fGgiqIf.png)

Comment: Run: hp-check -t look for the section pp-build=, it should =yes.

Comment: it said =no.
so i followed these [steps](http://hplipopensource.com/node/217)
now the "parrallel port" option is enabled. but when i click it i got the message "No Devices Found'

and if i use hp-setup -i

  
Using connection type: par

error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.

Comment: run hp-doctor then hp-check.  Read for any missing dependencies.  The program is heavily dependant upon them.  It will ask you to automatically install them.

Comment: Indeed, it asks.
I have 2 errors : python3-pyqt4 and gtk2-engines-pixbuf
but automatic and custom installations do not solve the problem :(
when i manually apt-get install <package name> it says <package name> is already the newest version.

Comment: sudo apt install build-essential python3-dev libqt4-dev  && sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4 && sudo apt-get update

Comment: the try the hp-check again

Comment: make sure to look for automatic installation

Comment: the result seems to be the same.
hp-check installs nothing. it's hp-doctor that asks for automatic installation.
unfortunatelly, even after your command the 2 errors are the same. :(
still 2 missing dependencies.

Comment: Well you know what the exact issue is now.  I would make a seperate question detailing the dependencies you need and what you tried with errors you got.

Comment: Alright so in your opinion, if I can solve this dependencies problem, I will be able to print using hplip without my computer to completely crash ?

Comment: Yes, if it sees no errors during hp-doctor hp-check, then it should run well.  I only buy HP printers for linux and have had nothing but success once you install these dependencies.  Just make sure to read the output, as they tend to tell you to run the program issuing a different command.